# When installing a service pack on one instance will this hinder the running of the other instances on a standalone SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, service-pack

I have a SQL Server 2016 with an instance A and an instance B. Both have SP1 installed, no reporting server.

Can I assume that, when I install SP2 on instance B only, that, while installing, the running of instance A will not be hindered ? (no restarting of the SQL Server service)

Since sqlbrowser is a shared feature, it will also be updated, will this hinder any remote access to instance A (fix port) for the time of the install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Service Pack installation process will identify if there are any files in use that will necessitate a restart of the server.

Each instance has it's own independent set of executables, so instance B should not be affected by installation of a new service pack on instance A.

The SQL Server Browser Service will be restarted pretty quickly, however there may be a short period of time where name resolution for named instances may not work as expected.

Best practice for this kind of work on a production server is to schedule it to occur during a period of low or no activity.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I assume that, when I install SP2 on instance B only, that, while installing, the running of instance A will not be hindered ? (no restarting of the sqlserver-service)

No the Instance A will not be restarted both instances work mutually exclusive. Regarding shared features Service Pack only makes changes to certain features if there is some bug or enhancement I don't see anything related to SQL Browser service in SQL Server 2016 SP2 so I believe that should not be affected but I am not sure.

Comment: you mean, "the instance A will not be restarted" instead of started ?

Comment: @luc sorry for the mistake, you have keen eyes, have corrected it.

Comment: @luc I have removed some incorrect lines from my answer, you have no control over shared feature the selection is grayed out so you have to upgrade it when you install SP on any of the instance. I just tested this on my system

Comment: indeed, I was surprised this were possible now, thank you for verifying!